# Correct way to assign variables before a try/catch/finally

Tags: c#, exception-handling, excel

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

...

Excel.Application app = null;
Excel.Workbooks books = null;
Excel.Workbook book = null;

object[,] data;

try
{
    app = new Excel.Application();
    books = app.Workbooks;
    book = books.Open("C:\...");

    Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[1];
    Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
    data = range.Value;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
    //To Do...
}
finally
{
    book.Close();
    app.Quit();
}

//code that the uses data object from above e.g.
...
```

In the code above I have to declare the objects `app`, `books` and `book` outside of the `try` block so that I have access to them in the `finally` block. However if I do not assign anything to them (i.e. `Excel.Application app;` instead of `Excel.Application app = null;`) then the compiler complains about the line `app.Quit()` saying "Use of unassigned local variable...". So is it correct to assign `null` to `app` etc in this case?

Also `books` doesn't get used in the `finally` block so is it better to declare it as I have, or should I declare it in the `try` block?

Comment: The delecrations outside of the try-catch block are fine. What do you do when `app = new Excel.Application()` fails and book remains null? Your final block will throw a NullReferenceException then.

Comment: @dusky I see that, so what's the correct usage for this case?

Comment: Check book for null :) And don't do `throw ex;`, just use `throw` instead.

Comment: @dusky thanks the `throw ex` won't remain. OK so you're saying all I need to change is to wrap everything inside the finally in an `if` checking for nulls?

Comment: @dusky but also, checking `book` for null isn't quite correct because if the line `books.Open("C:\...")` fails, then I would still want to call `app.Quit()` right? So should I check them for being `null` individually?

Comment: Yes, check everything for null that can be null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two main issue I can see with your code:

1. `app` and `book` can potentially remain null and therefore your `finally` code has the potential to throw a `NullReferenceException`. You need to check for `null` first before calling methods on these objects.
2. The way you re-throw the exception will destroy its stacktrace. Instead of this:

   ```
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw ex;
       //To Do...
   }
   ```

   you should do this:

   ```
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       //To Do...
       throw;
   }
   ```

As to your question where to declare `books` - it best practice to limit the scope of variables and declare them as close to their use point as possible.

---

As mentioned in the comments if you want to pass a custom error message via the exception then the best way forward it to create a custom exception which accepts the original exception as a parameter. If you derive from `Exception` one of the constructors accepts an inner exception parameter. So something along these lines:

```
public class DocumentProcessingException : Exception
{
    public DocumentProcessingException(string message, Exception innerException) :
            base(message, innerException)
    { }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to add to the error message then without destroying the stack trace (which I must be honest I wouldn't know what to do with anyways)? So for example if I'm parsing an excel file row by row and hit an error, I'd like to add the row number to the error message...

Comment: @Dan If you want to add more info before rethrowing the exception, you should create a *new* exception with a more detailed message and the original exception as its inner exception. E.g., `throw new DocumentProcessingException("Failed on line 12", ex);`